# Jquery post not sending textarea value... I think

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so i have this form

```
<form action="post100.html" method="post">
   <fieldset>
      <label for="Pinboard_entry" class="floatL">Text: </label>
      <textarea id="Pinboard_entry" rows="6" cols="45" name="entry" class=""></textarea>
      <div class="fieldNotes">
         <span id="pinboardCharsCount">10000001</span>&nbsp;digits left
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="buttonArea">
         <input class="fieldBtnSubmit" value="Submit" type="submit">
         <input class="fieldBtnCancel" value="Reset" type="reset">
      </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

which i have to submit the textarea value through this jquery

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('Pinboard_entry');
textarea.value = "test";
var info = $('#Pinboard_entry').val();
$.post( "post100.html", {Pinboard_entry: info} );
```

And it should post a comment on a page saying "test", but nothing happens. Is it a problem with my jquery? I even tried putting an id in my form and sending with

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('Pinboard_entry');
textarea.value = "test";
$.post( "post100.html", $( "#form_id" ).serialize() );
```

after i change the form to

```
<form id="form_id" action="post100.html" method="post">
```

but still nothing happens. Am i doing something wrong when sending the post? I am very very new to jquery, learned it today so please if you know the problem keep that in mind when explaining.
Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: `<form id="form_id"` is missing in your html

Comment: I know, i added that line when i use  '$( "#form_id" ).serialize() ' i tought it was clear but i will change the question

Comment: I've made your example https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/bumua9b7/ , everything works fine

Comment: I dont understand, that doesnt mimic my program at all, only the form